# Is it possible to process Multipart CSV File uploaded from web application using Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I want to convert csv file contains student data to **List** and insert into database.  I have gone through many examples from various sources, none of them provides answer for **batch processing csv files uploaded from Web UI** using **spring batch**. All examples process csv files located in resource folder (classpath). 
Please help me to process csv files uploaded using Post Method as below.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity saveStudentDetails(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile studentCSV) {
   //code to initate batch processing for studentCSV file
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/save")
        public ReturnFormat uploadCSV(@RequestParam("files")  MultipartFile file )
        {
            return uploadingService.uploadCSV( file );
        }
```

Service class will be like

```
    public void uploadCSV (MultipartFile multipartFile)
    {
        ReturnFormat rf = new ReturnFormat();
        SuccessErrorList selist = new SuccessErrorList();
        try
        {
            File file = convertMultiPartToFile( multipartFile );

    }

    private File convertMultiPartToFile( MultipartFile file ) throws IOException
    {
        File convFile = new File( file.getOriginalFilename() );
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( convFile );
        fos.write( file.getBytes() );
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the response. but i want to convert student csv to List of Students and uploaded it to database.

Comment: i have a code of uploading questions from CSV. you want to have a look on that?